# Retrieve a complex field from elasticsearch using java api

Tags: elasticsearch, java

I need to know how I can retrieve a complex field from elasticsearch using java api in a bool query, the field look like:

```
author: {
     "es": { [ {"name" : "Name 1" , "alias" : "alias1" },
             {"name" : "Name 2" , "alias" : "alias2" }]            
           }
       }
```

Should I change my mapping? "author" is a field in my elasticsearch index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code :)

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = boolQuery() .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", "")) .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("alias", ""));



        SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("your index");
        searchRequestBuilder.setQuery(queryBuilder);


        SearchResponse response = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();


        System.out.println(response.getHits().getTotalHits());
        for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits()){
            list.add(hit.getSourceAsString());
        }
```